# Unable to add dependency module in gradle intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using gradle (IDE: Intellij) to run my automated scripts. I've few modules Module A, Module B, Module C so on. I'm trying add module B as a dependent module to module C. I tried

a. specifying it in module C build.gradle file

b. tried a cyclic reference as in both the modules's build.gradle file (module B and module C)

c. tried under Project Structure --> module dependency

d. in the global build.gradle which is a common file for module A,B,C

e. Tried File | Invalidate Caches

```
 dependencies {
        testCompile ":modulename" --> I tried with single quote and double quotes
    }
```

I'm trying to access a class from module B in module C class but it's saying class not found. Both the class have public access.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the `dependencies` block syntax is slightly wrong. Try this:

```
project(":moduleC").dependencies {
    testCompile project(":moduleB")
}
```

Comment: It said .dependencies cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Thanks to [this](https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/) post.

The solution that worked for me is in the module specific gradle file, enter it as

```
dependencies{
    testCompile project(':moduleA').sourceSets.test.output

}
```